# How can I find out what quick action launched a lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I'm trying to create a dynamic lightning component that could be fired from different quick actions on different objects.  How do i find out what button launched my lightning component?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please take a minute to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) then [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/296314/edit) your question to add detail that shows that you have spent some time researching your problem and just what the issue is you face without knowing which action was fired. It could well be that you don't actually need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to tell which specific action was fired, but you can force:hasRecordId/recordId and force:hasSObjectName/objectApiName to determine the record Id and object type.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  So i wouldn't be able to have this component attached to multiple buttons on one object if i wanted to?  because i'd have no way of knowing which button fired it

Comment: @johnlxc Nope. The usual method is to create the common component, then pass in data from a wrapper component. That's how you can figure out which button was which, but it's not as simple as just getting the button/action name.